# Selector for parent body from popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a situation where I need to apply Styles on a POPUP based on if "Opener window" of that POP has a style class defined on it.

```
<html>
   <body class="myClass"> 
     <input type="button" onClick="Open('xyz.html')"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now on `xyz.html` I want to have a CSS selector which can toggle some style based on if `parent.html` has `class="myClass"`.

Is it possible without Jquery?

If not: what alternatives I have for this including Jquery and Javascript?

Please note: `parent.html` is opening `xyz.html` they are both separate windows.

Comment: yes you can use [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Is it possible(without Jquery)? so why add `jquery` and `javacript` tag add in question

Comment: because if it's not possible, i would like Jquery or javascript solution as an alternate.

Comment: Is it not possible using CSS selectors?

Comment: This question needs clarification. Is the code posted part of xyz.html? Is the popup a separate window? Where is the toggled custom class applied?

Comment: It is possible using CSS selector. Check the code snippet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068508/css-selector-for-parent-body-from-popup/46068625#46068625

Comment: @Joshua , xyz.html is a separate window, parent.html is opening xyz.html in separate pop up.

Comment: _“based on if `parent.html` has `class="myClass"`”_ - a document never “has a class” - at most elements contained _within_ that document can have classes. And no, this is of course not possible using CSS - CSS knows nothing about “windows”, “popups” or any other of those imaginary constructs, and it can not select “across document boundaries” either.

Comment: Thanks CBroe for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jQuery to check it. You can make use of simple CSS for it. Check the code below. Here, if `container` has the class `my-class`. The property of `background-color` will be applied to the popup. Otherwise, it won't. Check the code and try using the same with and without the `my-class` in the `container`.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.popup').toggleClass('active')
})
```

```css
.popup {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
.popup.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.container.my-class .popup {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container my-class">
  <button>Click</button>
  <div class="popup"> HAI </div>
</div>
```